# average cycling speed 12km/h

Tags: training

I am now in training for cycling. Long time didn't got into bike. I am using a 21 gear mountain bike with highest gear, and around 70 - 80rpm. What's surprise me is my average speed only 12km/h(recorded from strava) and 14km/h(recorded from mapmyride).

I was wondering whether i am using the wrong gear? I thought that the higher with the same rpm will move faster than a lower gear with same rpm.

12km/h is much slower than my expectation. I expect 70rpm would be 20km/h or more.

Comment: It is slow, but everyone moves at their own pace.  Select your gear based on the effort required to maintain a decent cadence (70-80 is good).  If you feel you can put out more effort (over the distance you're doing) then use a higher gear.  (Your highest gear would be the largest front sprocket and the smallest rear sprocket.)  If the highest gear is not satisfactory, you can probably get the rear cluster changed for one with smaller cogs.

Comment: Plugging typical tooth counts for entry-level hard tail mtbs into http://sheldonbrown.com/gears/ I doubt the gears themselves are the problem if you're really doing 70+ rpm (I'm assuming 28-38-48 chain rings, the smallest sprocket might be 12 to 15 teeth)

Comment: @DanielRHicks i tested all the gear and pretty sure that left 3 right 7 is the hardest to pedal. Yup. I am able to maintain 70-80 rpm per hour for more than an hour but what i am uncertain that it is 12km/h a normal speed for full 21 gear for 70-80 rpm. Wondering if that is my cycling problem, or is it a problem with the bike or the app i use

Comment: Get a stopwatch and measure yourself riding a mile or something, without traffic lights and stop signs. Then, calculate it out by hand if you think its the gps. But I doubt it is, and your cadence is lower than you think it is.

Comment: Well, you can time yourself for a KM or two, if there is a convenient stretch of road with KM markers.  Or purchase an inexpensive cyclometer (though the quality of those has really gone downhill for the past 10 years or so).

Comment: i am riding in a park where there is no traffic. both strava and mapmyride shows an average of 0.7km per round and i took around 3 minutes to complete a cycle which makes around 14km/h. so mayb i can safely assume that that is not a gps problem?

Comment: @vincentsty strava and mapmyride will be using the same underlying gps data, so you can't dismiss that.  Both will cheat you (possibly by different amounts) in tight turns, so try a straight line with a clear view of the sky (then it's easy to grab the distance of google or a map and time with a stopwatch).  All that said though, I doubt the GPS is making that much difference.

Comment: @ChrisH i have just measure the distance from google map. is approximate 700m as well. so i guess the problem is with the gear, bicycle or my riding behaviour

Comment: @vincentsty, OK, so either look up or count the number of teeth on the pair of gears you're using, plug them into any online gear calculator with your tyre size and you'll get the relationship between speed and cadence.  I suspect your cadence estimates are way off given what you've checked already.

Comment: Yeah. A lot of people I know have cadences in the 50's but think its much higher.

Comment: If you are sure on the distance and gears then what is left if cadence.  How are you measuring 70-80 rpm.

Comment: i measure the rpm by calculate how many my right leg turns per minute. My right leg starting from bottom, and turn to bottom again i count as 1 round.

Comment: i just know that is a 27 gear bicycle as i rented the bicycle(3 gear left, 7 gear right). but not really sure with the crank and casette

Comment: You may want to consider to purchase a pair of slick tires since I assume you use original knobby tires. Once you change to narrower and slicker tires, you can feel the difference!

Comment: See the answer from Batman and the calculator.  It is just not adding up.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit tedious to do so, but not rocket science:  Count the number of teeth on the largest front cog and the smallest rear cog.  Either report those numbers here or plug them in to a gear ratio calculator.

Comment: One more thing to check: that the gears are actually shifting as you'd expect, i.e. that you actually have 7 different gears at the back and 3 at the front. If the top chain ring is indicated but you're actually in the middle one that could explain it.

Comment: Did this question go anywhere?  Its over a year later now.

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate your speed vs cadence using this [online calculator](http://sheldonbrown.com/gears/). You want your cadence to be roughly 80 rpm (60 being the lower bound).

With a 42t chainring and 14t cog in the back (not uncommon for a 26" mtb -- this is big ring in front, small in back), you should be doing around 31 kph at 80 RPM, so chances are you're either spinning too fast in a too low gear or spinning too slow in a too high gear.

Answer (score 0):

You say the highest gear on a 21 speed mtb bike. This would be the largest chain-wheel & the smallest cog. The largest chain-wheel is most likely a 48t. The smallest cog could be in the range of 11t to 14t. Let's say it's a 14t.  At 70-80 rpm with a 48t x 14t, your speed would be somewhere around 30kph to 34kph.  (any cog smaller than 14t would produce and even faster speed) If you are truly turning 70-80 rpms (how are you checking this?) and if your speed is only 12 to 14kph then you are not in the highest gear.
Shift to the highest gear. Now LOOK at the position of the chain. Is the chain on the outside/largest chain-ring and the smallest rear cog?

Comment: I think this would be the case. Either they aren't actually in the highest gear, or they aren't measuring cadence properly.  Even if you had a very small highest gear like 30-14, you'd still be getting 24 km/h at 80 rpm.